# How can I format this String with double x,y,total to two decimal places. output = (x + " + " + y + " = " + total);

Tags: string, format, double, decimal

How can I format this String with double x,y,total to two decimal places. String output = (x + " + " + y + " = " + total);

Comment: I do not know if this question is worth answering . . .

Comment: Well you were willing to spend your time be condescending so.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String ouput = String.format("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f",x,y,total);
System.out.println(output);
```

will give you the output with 2 decimal places or you can use `DecimalFormat` as well.